# Resources for learning the difference between present perfect and past simple in context

Tags: discussion

**Update:** I'm not looking for an explanation to the two specific sentences below. I'm looking for a learning resource which gathers examples in the form presented.

As [Canonical Post #2: What is the perfect, and how should I use it?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13255/canonical-post-2-what-is-the-perfect-and-how-should-i-use-it) puts it

> The English “perfect” is deeply puzzling for learners

As a non-native speaker on the C1/C2 level, I can't stress how annoying it to put so much effort into trying to understand it, yet still making mistakes - I think mainly because this tense doesn't exist at all in my native language (Polish).

What I'm looking for, and I couldn't find it anywhere, is a website or a book that gives two sentences with the only difference being past simple or present perfect - then explains in details what is the difference in meaning and in what context one would be preferred over the other:

***1a.** Thanks, I've had a great time.*

***1b.** Thanks, I had a great time.*

***Usage:** Sentence 1a would be used in situations like .... Sentence 1b would be used in situations like ..., because of ....*

Just that. The more examples, the better. Is there anything out there?

Comment: Can downvoters explain why the downvotes?

Comment: In any context where #1 is acceptable, #2 is equally valid, and means *exactly* the same thing (and I'd guess Simple Past #2 is actually more common). But if we cast the "great time" further into the past - for example, *Thanks for inviting me to your party **last week**. I had a great time*, ONLY Simply Past is acceptable. You can't use Present Perfect when talking about last week's party - it's only valid for ***very recent*** events (typically, *when you're leaving the party*; you can't even use it tomorrow morning to thank ***last night's*** party-giver).

Comment: Thanks FumbleFingers. As mentioned, I'm not looking for an explanation to those two specific sentences. Using perfect over other tenses has many different flavours and I'm trying to find a learning resource that gathers a lot of examples exactly in the form presented. I updated my question to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: I don't understand. If you're *not* interested in the difference between your two example sentences above, why did you include them? If you seek a much broader understanding of Perfect usages, I'm inclined to closevote in favour of StoneyB's excellent "canonical post". Otherwise, it looks like an Off Topic "request for resources" anyway.

Comment: ...there are plenty of "What's the difference?" questions about Present Perfect / Simple Past right here on ELL. For example, [went or has gone?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/235028/) and [has done or did when using "during"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/197461/) and [Did vs Has done](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/94544/) and ["was" vs "has been"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/170269/was-vs-has-been) and many, many more.

Comment: The sentences are there to show the format of what I'd expect to find in the external learning resource. I read the canonical post and it's amazing, but it's not exhaustive in terms of examples that would solidify my knowledge.

The example questions you linked are more or less what I'm looking for, but in a more condensed structure and with explanation provided by the same person so it doesn't repeat itself. Most of the English books or articles on perfect provide just a single sentence, not comparing it to the same in another tense, if that makes sense

Comment: Bonus points for some interactive quiz/test along the way :) If such resource doesn't exist, it's fine. I couldn't find any. I just thought to ask here, because maybe someone is aware of it.

Comment: This question *is* an Off Topic request for resources, so I'll be voting to migrate it to ELL Meta (where it would be On Topic). But I doubt there's any "reputable / reliable" publication for what you seek anyway - and in my experience, anything you *do* find is likely to be very poor quality material (often from non-native Anglophone sources), so perhaps the best resource available to you is ELL anyway. You just need to ask *specific* questions about specific points you're having trouble understanding.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get back to it - if ELL Meta is more appropriate then sure, I didn't know querying for resources if off topic

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree, it's off topic, but probably a valid question for ELL Meta. I vote to move it.

Comment: I don't know why 3 people have *downvoted* (as opposed to voting to migrate to Meta), but I've upvoted to try and redress the balance a bit. Just because it's (non-intuitively?) Off Topic doesn't mean the asker should be *penalised*. Especially a relatively new user who obviously wasn't aware of this particular restriction.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a request for resources, which is explicitly off-topic for this site

Comment: @gotube but we have a tag [tag:resource-request] on this Meta. I agree on the main site it is off-topic.

Comment: @mdewey Learn something every day. Reopened. Also, FWIW, your link points to ell, not ell.meta, so to anyone following it, it looks like there's no such tag. Not sure if that's why I disregarded your comment back in September